# Can I travel with my video game to Germany?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, germany

I will be going to Germany next Monday and I will be there from 20 to 22 days, and I would like to take my PlayStation 4 with me, since sometimes I have problems to sleep. Is this possible. I come from Brazil (Brazilian).

Can I enter the country with it?

Comment: What exactly is your concern?  Will it work or will you have to pay duty on it?

Comment: I d like to know if it is legal to enter the country with it. Just edited the question.

Comment: At worst you will have to pay duty.

Comment: :( Oh really? right before I enter Germany?

Comment: When you enter Schengen.  Though I doubt it will be the case.

Comment: @Karlson For customs, the relevant unit is the EU, not the Schengen area, but you typically clear customs and pay duty at your final destination and not during a layover. So you don't necessarily have to pay duty when you enter the Schengen area.

Comment: You fly half way around the world to play computer games?

Answer (score 8):

SECOND UPDATE:
First thanks to Jonathan Reez for asking, here is the source again:

[German customs site](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Duties-and-taxes/Travellers-allowances/travellers-allowances_node.html)

After a short controversy in the comments below I phoned the customs and asked for clarification:

If you intend to bring *non-consumable* items in general to Germany *which you will bring back home*, you do not need to pay duty, excise or VAT.
So for the Playstation 4, you can bring it from Brazil and you will have no problems to bring to Germany.

If you bring *consumable* items like cigarettes, alcohol, medicine or fuel you are free to import the given amount which is counted for personal use. If the amount of these substances is higher, customs duty must be paid.  It **does not matter** if it is in the baggage or if you intend to bring the same amount out of Germany again (only transit visit).

If you intend to leave *non-consumable* goods in Germany (in contrast to not bringing it back home like in the third paragraph), you may do that without paying duty for the following values:

- Goods up to a value of 300 euros for land travellers.
- Goods up to a value of 430 euros for air/sea travellers.
- Goods up to a value of 175 euros for travellers under 15 years of age.

[If you intend to leave something more valuable, you can research the amount of duty and excise in this table which unfortunately only exist in German](http://www.zoll.de/DE/Privatpersonen/Reisen/Rueckkehr-aus-einem-Nicht-EU-Staat/Zoll-und-Steuern/Ueberschreiten-Reisefreimengen/beispiele_zollsaetze.html?nn=18670).

[As traveller you may import fraudulent or copyrighted material for your own personal use **as long as it is not commercial**](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Restrictions/Counterfeiting-and-piracy/counterfeiting-and-piracy_node.html). Therefore you need to sometimes sign a waiver. As German customs are notorious for intercepting post packages and shipments from buyers in Germany, I erroneously assumed that travellers have the same restrictions. Mea culpa.

German customs:
Phone: +49 351 44834-510
Mail: info.privat@zoll.de

Comment: Is there a source for that information?

Comment: That's not German law, that's EU law. But I am not sure the threshold really applies to *used* goods you will reexport shortly (personal effects), if not in principle, at least in practice.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. The 175/300/430€ limits apply to items bought outside the EU and brought back by EU residents. The limits do not apply to luggage of non-EU residents when visiting the EU as long as they don't intend to leave the items within the EU.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo The section is from German customs and explicitly mentions "If you are entering **Germany from a non-EU state**, most goods carried by you are tax/duty-free unless they exceed certain quantity and value limits. Certain goods, however, you may not (or only under certain conditions) import."  and **exactly that section** is cited. I am now seriously angry because it took a while to get it together and you are claiming it is completely wrong without giving a backing source ! Either source your statement or delete your comment.

Comment: @ThorstenS. I've already provided the link to the correct information page in my answer. You are linking to the regulations for 'traveller's allowance' and your mistake is to assume that tourist's luggage falls into that category. It obviously does not, otherwise all tourists having luggage worth more than 430€ (and I assume most tourists do) would have to pay import duty when entering the EU.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo I was away the last weekend. I will call customs by phone today because on the other hand it is not plausible that I can put my luggage as far as it will go with cigarettes and whiskey and do not pay custom duty.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo So, updated the information. You are right that the limits do not apply for **some** goods (including the Playstation) which will be transported back and I therefore apologize for my crankyness but your answer is only partially right because you did not distinguish consumables and non-consumables.

Comment: @ThorstenS. That's because there is no legal difference between 'consumable' and 'non-consumable' items in the German or EU customs regulations. Strictly speaking are 'personal effects reasonably required for the journey' unless 'subject to a prohibition or restriction or to any other special formality' covered by the regulations, see EEC 2454/93, article 232, 235, 236 and 563. There is no strict exception for consumable items.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo If you look at the post, you will find a phone number below. Please print out the EEC 2454/93, article 232, 235, 236 and 563 and explain the receptionist that you are unsatisfied with the explanation given. Discuss that in detail with him/her using your detailed knowledge, update **your answer** with the correct interpretation, cite the appropiate paragraphs in detail and wait until your answer is voted to the top. Put yourself through the paces.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, as a tourist visiting Germany, you may (with very few exceptions) temporarily import most objects without paying duties or taxes, as long as you intend to bring them with you when leaving Germany again. You can find extensive information and a list of exceptions on this [web page](http://www.zoll.de/EN/Private-individuals/Travel/Entering-Germany/Duties-and-taxes/Baggage/baggage_node.html) from German Customs.